# Add Mesh issue after creating a Geometry node to scatter

Tags: geometry-nodes

I decided to have a go with Geometry nodes (Distribute points on faces) to scatter 500 water droplets randomly across a flat plane. All went well, or at least I think so. Unfortunately now when I try and add a new mesh or light to the scene, it adds 500 items as if it is using the Node.
Any idea what have I have missed.
[image]

Comment: The collection used in gn is the default collection where new objects are created. Change the selected/active collection in the outliner.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.